# gnuplot "datafile separator" does not work

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I am trying to plot two columns of data (date, weight) and in general it works. My problem is, that I have to separate the columns with a space, although I'd prefer to use a comma.

Example from the data file (weight is 85.73 kg on 24th of July 2014):

```
"2014-07-24 06:02:42",85.73
```

This is my current plot script (line numbers inserted for easier reference):

```
  1 set grid
  2 set datafile separator ","
  3 set ylabel 'Weight (kg)'
  4 set xdata time
  5 set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
  6 set xrange ['"2014-01-01 00:01"':'"2019-08-01 00:01"']
  7 set style data lines
  8 plot "weight" using 1:2
```

I can set the separator in line 2 to any value I like, it does not work. I will get the following errors, although gnuplot changed the separator (`gnuplot> how datafile separator` reports `datafile fields separated by any of 1 characters ","`)

```
$ gnuplot weight.plot 
"weight.plot", line 8: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot "weight" using 1:2
                       ^
"weight.plot", line 8: all points y value undefined!
```

I am using `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2` on Linux Mint

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When gnuplot is reading from a cvs file it strips out any double quotes that might be redundantly delimiting each field.  As I recall this is done for consistency with MSExcel, which does not distinguish between 123 and "123".  So by the time the program tries to apply `timefmt` the quotes have already been removed, and the format doesn't match.   It will work if you simply remove the extra double quotes from `set timefmt` and `set xrange`:

```
set grid
set datafile separator ","
set ylabel 'Weight (kg)'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2014-01-01 00:01":"2019-08-01 00:01"]
set style data lines
set table   # for debugging
plot "weight" using 1:2

   # Curve 0 of 1, 1 points
   # Curve title: ""weight" using 1:2"
   # x y type
   "2014-07-24 06:02:42"  85.73  i
```